# Trying trigger biometric prompt without authentication

Tags: react-native, biometrics

Im working on an app that requires a PIN to allow certain tasks (purchasing, dealing with credit cards, etc). I would like to add the ability to use biometrics.

I want to be able to ask for permission to use the biometrics without actually authenticating anything the first time.

for example, the flow would be as follows:
 - user logs in

- creates a PIN
- App asks if they would like to use biometrics in the future
- next time when PIN is required, authentication prompt appears.

the current flow:

- user logs in
- creates a PIN
- App asks if they would like to use biometrics in the
  future
- next time when PIN is required, OS prompt appears asking if
  user is ok with app using biometrics.

THEN

- authentication prompt appears.

Ive played around with react-native-touch-id, react-native-biometrics and a few others.

I know i could have it triggered when i first ask to set the PIN but the system prompt options are not customizable.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: Where can I find modules related to biometric and PIN?